# Google Map style - can't produce a dark style that shows buildings

Tags: google-maps

On [mapstyle.withgoogle.com](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) I can choose several themes. Standard shows building structure just nicely for my purpose. I can change its colors and everything works fine. But I need it dark.

If I choose a dark theme, there are no building structures to be seen, no matter what I do. (Well it shows some geometry, but not as much as the standard theme). I tried all kinds of features and settings. (Why is that?)

So, back to the standard theme, making it dark also has its limitations. No matter what I try, country areas won't get dark.

It appears that you have to start from a base theme that comes with a predefined set of parameters that cannot be changed. However, when I check the resulting JSON, there is no mention of that. So I guess I must be wrong.

Then I tried to manually merge this standard theme with the dark one, but the result just isn't satisfying. And it's funny, because I "merge" with an empty array []

Basically I want a map that looks like [this](https://snazzymaps.com/style/3854/dango-red). (Well, that's "snazzy maps", I hope I don't have to switch to another maps provider and so on. Btw, I'm developing on android.)

Here is my style.json (looks like a waste without buildings):

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#002eea"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#002eea"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#002eea"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#002eea"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#181818"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please, somebody tell me I'm just tired and should try from scratch tomorrow, selectively testing every single entry of my style.

Answer (score 1):

Once you edit the theme from the original, there is no way to get the map to render buildings/structures.

Answer (score 0):

could be you are looking for

landscape.man_made

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#004040"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show and change the building colors in here, see attached image

https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works for only the web, not iOS or Android. Google Androids SDK does not support the dark theme. You should change the map provider